# What does the preposition "upon" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

This context comes from the video game "Divinity Original Sin II"
It's a  fragment of a letter I found in the game:

"BY REQUEST OF THE DIVINE ORDER

Certain Sourcerers known as 'Godwoken' are to be identified **upon** the agreement of both parties to the terms of this contract. These 'Godwoken' will be located by the contractor and disposed of in a timely, quiet, and seemly manner."

"**on**"

a. Used to indicate a source or basis: *"We will reach our judgments not on intentions or on promises but on deeds and on results"* (Margaret Thatcher). (source: American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language)

Is this the correct definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Upon** does mean *on*, but not always in the sense of "using as a basis".  If you look at [the examples in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/upon), you will see one like

- She was admitted to his office immediately upon her arrival.

which is the same usage as in your question.  If you look at the definition of [**on**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on), you will find

> 3 — used as a function word to indicate a time frame during which something takes place **or an instant, action, or occurrence when something begins or is done** : *on arriving home, I found your letter*

I would interpret *upon* in your example the same way: "...will be identified **when both parties have agreed to this contract**", not "*because* both parties agree" or "*on the basis of* agreement to this contract".

Comment: Yeah, it made sense as soon as I read your answer. Thanks:)